# How to keep Visual Studio files off my source code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I want to keep my source code files on Google Drive, but Visual Studio (VS2013 to be specific) creates some big databases and built binaries (sdf, pdb, etc.) in same directory, as my source code. My internet connection can't really handle those big files and blocks entire Drive sync for 20 minutes or more. Is there some way to store those bulky files out of my Google Drive?

Comment: Use formal revision control software like Git or SVN. Other than that your question is off-topic and more suited for sites like [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: I seem to remember that those files end up in the build directory, but maybe my memory is wrong. And yes, use a proper version control system, and not only does it help with he backup, but you can do "Hmm, this is broken, I need to go find when I broke it", and such.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to have your workspace in your Google Drive folder.

If you really must store your source code on Google Drive you could maintain a bare git repository on Google Drive and push commits from your workspace repository to the repository in your Google Drive folder.

With a proper .gitignore file none of the big databases and binary files will get into your git repository and so will not be pushed into your Google Drive folder.